# Can I access my oracle database if I select the Desktop class when I install oracle database in my server

Tags: database, oracle

Can some body tell me that whether I can access my oracle database from my notebook, if I select the Desktop class when I install oracle database in my server.
And if I can, what I should do? (I just want to try to connect my oracle database in server from my notebook using SQL developer tool.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmc3J.png)

Comment: A database you can't access would be pretty useless....

Comment: I want to know whether I can access Oracle database in server  from pc if I select Desktop Class when installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessibility doesn't differ based on Server / Desktop class. This two class is basically for configuration. For example, if you select server class, then it is expected that you are installing it for production environment which may require to configure it with different options. So, if you select desktop class, it will take you to the simple screen with minimum configuration items. So, you can install desktop class on the server too.

> To connect, you need connection string. Yes, you can connect from sqldeveloper too from your laptop. You need to create connection string by providing username, password, server ip/address, port, sid name. 
>   Check the screen shot in this link: 
>   https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/paas/accessdbinstance/images/AccessDBInstance_OBE_connect_db_service.jpg&imgrefurl=https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f%3Fp%3D44785:112:2859948781695::::P112_CONTENT_ID,P112_PREV_PAGE:11368&h=417&w=670&tbnid=oQJTUwkQNk7MDM:&tbnh=131&tbnw=211&usg=__5lgQ5gu8SrkZL9KoGkU0HP0mugk=&vet=10ahUKEwielOGHgvTTAhUTSI8KHTtJDOEQ9QEIJTAA..i&docid=d34NHq-Krt96NM&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwielOGHgvTTAhUTSI8KHTtJDOEQ9QEIJTAA